# Woocommerce Custom Payment Gateway Not Redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a WC payment gateway which was build and working until WP version 4.1. Today I started testing it on WP 4.9.8 and WC 3.5.1.

When I try to complete purchase the payment gateway is not taking me to the payment screen to fill credit card details. It get stuck on redirection state.

Hope someone can help me out to solve this.

Below the image reference and the code I am using:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: CustomPaymentGateway
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_mpay', 0);

function init_mpay() {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) return;

    class woocommerce_mpay extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public function __construct() { 
            global $woocommerce;

            $this->id           = 'mpay';
            $this->method_title = __('MPay', 'mpay-chearaan-woo');
            $this->icon         = plugins_url( 'mpay.png', __FILE__ );
            $this->has_fields   = false;
            $this->notify_url   = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'woocommerce_mpay', home_url( '/' ) ) );

            // Load the form fields.
            $this->init_form_fields();

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_settings();

            // Define user set variables
            $this->mpayurl              = $this->settings['mpayurl'];
            $this->title                = $this->settings['title'];
            $this->description          = $this->settings['description'];
            $this->merchantid           = $this->settings['merchantid'];
            $this->hashKey              = $this->settings['hashKey'];
            $this->transactionDate      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
            $this->woo_version          = $this->get_woo_version();

            // Actions
            add_action('init', array(&$this, 'successful_request'));
            add_action('woocommerce_api_woocommerce_mpay', array( &$this, 'successful_request' ));
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_mpay', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));
            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0.0', '>=' ) ) {
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ));
            } else {
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ));
            }
        } 

        /**
         * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields
         */
        function init_form_fields() {

            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'checkbox', 
                                'label' => __( 'Enable MPay', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => 'yes'
                            ), 
                'mpayurl' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'UAT/Production:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'checkbox', 
                                'label' => __( 'UAT', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => 'yes'
                            ), 
                'title' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Title:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'The title which the user sees during checkout.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => __( 'MPay Online Payment Gateway', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' )
                            ),
                'description' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Description:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'textarea', 
                                'description' => __( 'Description which the user sees during checkout.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => __('Pay securely through MPay\'s Secure Servers.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo')
                            ),
                'merchantid' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Merchant ID:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'Please enter your Merchant ID as provided by MPay.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => ''
                            ),
                'hashKey' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Merchant hashKey:', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'Please enter your Merchant hashKey as provided by MPay.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo' ), 
                                'default' => ''
                            )
                );

        }


        public function admin_options() {
            ?>
            <h3>MPay</h3>
            <p><?php _e('MPay works by sending the user to MPay to enter their payment information.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo'); ?></p>

            <table class="form-table">
            <?php
                // Generate the HTML For the settings form.
                $this->generate_settings_html();
            ?>
            </table><!--/.form-table-->
            <?php
        } // End admin_options()

        /**
         * There are no payment fields, but we want to show the description if set.
         **/
        function payment_fields() {
            if ($this->description) echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
        }

        /**
         * Generate the button link
         **/
        public function generate_mpay_form( $order_id ) {
            global $woocommerce;


            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            if ($this->mpayurl == "yes"){
                $mpay_adr = "https://pcimdex.mpay.my/mdex2/payment/eCommerce";
            }else{
                $mpay_adr = "https://www.mdex.my/mdex/payment/eCommerce";
            }


            $sHash = strtoupper(hash('sha256', $this->hashKey."Continue".str_pad($this->merchantid, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad($order->id, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(($order->order_total*100), 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)));
            $mpay_args = array(
                'secureHash'        => $sHash,
                'mid'               => str_pad($this->merchantid, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'invno'             => str_pad($order->id, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'amt'               => str_pad(($order->order_total*100), 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'desc'              => str_pad("Order No ".$order_id, 255, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT),
                'postURL'           => $this->notify_url,
                'phone'             => $order->billing_phone,
                'email'             => $order->billing_email,
                'param'             => 'WC|V1'
            );

            $mpay_args_array = array();

            foreach ($mpay_args as $key => $value) {
                $mpay_args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'. $value .'" /><br>';
            }

            wc_enqueue_js('
                jQuery(function(){
                            jQuery("body").block(
                                { 
                                    message: "<img src=\"'.$woocommerce->plugin_url().'/images/uploading.gif\" alt=\"Redirecting…\" style=\"float:left; margin-right: 10px;\" />'.__('Thank you for your order. We are now redirecting you to MPay to make payment.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo').'", 
                                    overlayCSS: 
                                    { 
                                        background: "#fff", 
                                        opacity: 0.5 
                                    },
                                    css: { 
                                        padding:        18, 
                                        textAlign:      "center", 
                                        color:          "#555", 
                                        border:         "2px solid #aaa", 
                                        backgroundColor:"#fff", 
                                        cursor:         "wait",
                                        lineHeight:     "30px"
                                    } 
                                });
                            jQuery("#submit_mpay_payment_form").click();
                        });
            ');

        return '<form action="'.$mpay_adr.'" method="post">
                    ' . implode('', $mpay_args_array) . '
                    <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_mpay_payment_form" value="'.__('Pay via MPay', 'mpay-chearaan-woo').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.$order->get_cancel_order_url().'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'mpay-chearaan-woo').'</a>
                </form>';           

        }

        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result
         **/
        function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            if($this->woo_version >= 2.1){
                $redirect = $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true );           
            }else if( $this->woo_version < 2.1 ){
                $redirect = add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id'))));
            }else{
                $redirect = add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id'))));
            }

            return array(
                'result'    => 'success',
                'redirect'  => $redirect
            );

        }

        /**
         * receipt_page
         **/
        function receipt_page( $order ) {

            echo '<p>'.__('Please click the button below to pay with MPay.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo').'</p>';

            echo $this->generate_mpay_form( $order );

        }

        /**
         * Server callback was valid, process callback (update order as passed/failed etc).
         **/
        function successful_request($mpay_response) {
            global $woocommerce;


            if (isset($_GET['wc-api']) && $_GET['wc-api'] == 'woocommerce_mpay') {
                /** need to trim from result **/
                $Url_result = $_GET['result'];
                $order = new WC_Order( (int) substr($Url_result,7,20) );
                $tranID = (int)substr($Url_result,1,6);

                if (substr($Url_result,0,1) == '0'){
                    $r_status = 0;
                }else{
                $r_status = 33;
                }

                /*
                $order = new WC_Order( (int) $_POST['invno'] );
                $r_status = (int) $_POST['result'];

                */

                if ($r_status == '0' ){

                    $order->payment_complete();

                    $order->add_order_note('MPay Payment was SUCCESSFUL '.'<br>AuthCode is '  . $tranID);

                    wp_redirect( $this->get_return_url($order) ); exit;
                    //wp_redirect( $this->order->get_checkout_order_received_url() ); exit;

                }else{

                    $order->update_status('failed', sprintf(__('MPay Payment Failed. Error Communicating with Bank.', 'mpay-chearaan-woo') ) );

                    wp_redirect($order->get_cancel_order_url()); exit;

                }
            }               
        }

        function get_woo_version() {

            // If get_plugins() isn't available, require it
            if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) )
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

            // Create the plugins folder and file variables
            $plugin_folder = get_plugins( '/woocommerce' );
            $plugin_file = 'woocommerce.php';

            // If the plugin version number is set, return it 
            if ( isset( $plugin_folder[$plugin_file]['Version'] ) ) {
                return $plugin_folder[$plugin_file]['Version'];

            } else {
                // Otherwise return null
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Add the gateway to WooCommerce
 **/
function add_mpay( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'woocommerce_mpay'; return $methods;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_mpay' );
```

[image]

Comment: Both the URLs of the payment gateway do not exist. Both of them return 404.
https://pcimdex.mpay.my/mdex2/payment/eCommerce
https://www.mdex.my/mdex/payment/eCommerce

Comment: @loic thanks, that URL was provided by the payment gateway and it was in the API Doc https://snag.gy/7zBSsJ.jpg